# Creating Shapefiles from MS SQL using ColdFusion/Java?

Tags: shapefile, sql, sql-server, java

A client wants to export, from their MS SQL server, data into Shapefiles. I've looked around for a starting ground and have heard Ogr2Ogr mentioned and it seems intimidating. So I was wondering if there were any libraries out there that did this or if anyone could suggest a place to start?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with Java then [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) provides [SQLServer](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/sqlserver.html) and [Shapefile](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/shape.html) datastores that will allow you to do the conversion.

But to be honest I'd use ogr2ogr, which is something like:

```
ogr2ogr "MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=geodb;tables=rivers;trusted_connection=yes" dst.shp
```

Comment: So if I were to set up ogr2ogr, about how much set up time is involved before I'm exporting SQL server informaiton into Shapefiles? And is there any solid documentation to this I'm missing?

Comment: about a minute! http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html shows you the basics followed by http://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html to find the sqlserver magic line.